# 1999 Eurovan fumes in cabin

Tags: vw, euro-van

I am smelling fumes inside the cabin of my 1999 Eurovan, enough to cause headaches and make me feel sick. It has happened before and seems to happen when the car has been working hard, AC has been running, and we are in stop and go traffic.

I've taken it in twice to my mechanic who has tested for fuel line leaks and looked around for the issue but not able to find the issue. It seems like the smell is coming from the front of the car near the driver.

Opening the windows doesn't seem to clear it when it is happening and but once the car cools down and the car is aired out, it may not happen again until the conditions are right. Unless, it is actually happening on a low level on shorter trips and I am not noticing it.

My question is, how can I prove that there are fumes inside the cabin, with a carbon monoxide detector perhaps?

And then, if they exist, how do we figure out where it is coming from? If it is an exhaust leak, how do we find it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking gas (petrol) fumes or exhaust fumes?

Comment: Are you familiar with a burnt oil smell or hot engine coolant odors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Car feels like it's filling up with fumes](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16261/car-feels-like-its-filling-up-with-fumes)

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a solid answer, but I can tell you that similar symptoms have been described many times over on the Yahoo group ev_update https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/ev_update/info
I have had similar symptoms on my 1997 EVC for several years as well. Only during hot weather as you point out. Search the Yahoo group for 'gurgling gas' or 'boiling gas'. It is often reported that if you stand outside by the gas cap and listen closely you will hear a boiling sound. If you remove the gas cap, there is a whoosh and the boiling sound stops. Then if you put the cap back on and wait for a few seconds the sound will start up again. Nobody has fully figured out what the issue is, but my own next move will be to replace the charcoal canister (when I get around to it).